# Inverting color of an image as it crosses a line?

Tags: html, css, image, transition

Here is a jsfiddle example of what I have at the moment. http://jsfiddle.net/arcgale/z39hf/2/

In this example I'm trying to invert the color of the image as it crosses into the black section region. Assume the height of the sections can change.

html:

```
    <img id="silhouette" src="http://hunterhaus.com/images/silhouette-black-mirrored.png"/>
    <section id="s1"></section>
    <section id="s2"></section>
    <section id="s3"></section>
```

css:

```
    section{height:500px; width:100%}
    #s1{background:blue}
    #s2{background:red}
    #s3{background:black}

    #silhouette{height:100px; width:100px; position:fixed; top:50px; left:50px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a demo for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/z39hf/7/

This is a very 'hacky', but maybe you can gain some insight from it? with a simple js scroll script, some css (overflow hidden and z-index) sleight of hand, you can obtain the effect you are looking for.

You might also be able to achieve this with a parallax plugin and overflow hidden.

the js:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $(".sticky").css({
            'top': scrollYpos,
        });

});
```

the html:

```
<section id="s1">
<img id="silhouette1" class="sticky" src="http://hunterhaus.com/images/silhouette-black-mirrored.png"/>

</section><img id="silhouette2" class="sticky" src="http://hunterhaus.com/images/silhouette-white-mirrored.png"/>

<section id="s2">


</section>
<section id="s3">
</section>
```

the css

```
body { margin:0;}
section{height:500px; width:100%;  overflow: hidden; position: relative;  }
#s1{background:blue; z-index:3;}
#s2{background:red;  }
#s3{background:black; z-index:4;}

#silhouette1{height:100px; width:100px; background:none;  }
#silhouette2{height:100px; width:100px; background:none;  z-index: 1;   }

.sticky { position: absolute;  display:block; }
```

Comment: Not only did that work perfectly, you figured out that I had a white version of the image without my mentioning it. Very impressed.

Comment: Likely the most cross-browser friendly option but note that it still requires two images, whereas using a filter (if your target browsers support it) can save you that extra image call.

Answer (score 1):

You'd like want to use a CSS image filter: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/

I believe webkit supports it at this time:

```
img {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);}
```

Comment: Knowing how to invert the image is simple. What gets complicated is when I try to invert it in parts... Like when I straddle it on the line between the red and black section, the top part of the image should be black while the bottom is white.

Comment: You'd have to use two images, stacked on top of each other--likely in DIVs. As you cross that line, you'd shrink the DIV on top to expose the reversed image below.